# buildr generate folder structure

Tags: buildr

I'm starting to use Apache buildr. 
As far as I understand, I always have to create the default folder structure (src/main/java etc) on my own? 
Is there a way to let buildr to this job for me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use Maven 2 archetype generation
- Run Buildr from the project dir. it sees the pom.xml and asks if you want
  to create a basic Buildr script from it.
- Run 'buildr eclipse' to generate .classpath and .project
- In Eclipse, import from a existing project in file system

Answer (score 0):

buildr is just a build tool, it is not meant to generate archetypes or build a website.

But you're right, sometimes you need to generate a new project, so I wrote a tiny shell script ([you can find the gist here](https://gist.github.com/jpcaruana/774597)).

Here is how it works :

```
$ ./createBuildrProject.sh jptest
Please answer '1' to the next question
To use Buildr you need a buildfile. Do you want me to create one?:
1. From directory structure
2. Cancel
?  1
Created /home/jp/src/perso/774597/jptest/buildfile
(in /home/jp/src/perso/774597/jptest, development)
Building jptest
Compiling jptest into /home/jp/src/perso/774597/jptest/target/classes
Compiling jptest:test into /home/jp/src/perso/774597/jptest/target/test/classes
Completed in 2.130s
./createBuildrProject.sh: ligne 17 : cd: jptest: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
(in /home/jp/src/perso/774597/jptest, development)
Generating Eclipse project for jptest
Writing /home/jp/src/perso/774597/jptest/.classpath
Writing /home/jp/src/perso/774597/jptest/.project
Completed in 0.025s
```

The output directories are like this :

```
$ tree jptest/
jptest/
├── buildfile
├── reports
│   └── junit
│       └── last_successful_run
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── Empty.java
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           └── EmptyTest.java
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   └── Empty.class
    ├── jptest-1.0.0.pom
    └── test
        └── classes
            └── EmptyTest.class

11 directories, 7 files
```

Hope this helps.